# how to stop page scrolling down while using jQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI Accordion in my App, 
one problem I have is: 
inside the 2nd tab, there is a very long form. 
Everytime when user come to the 2nd tab, the page automatically scroll down to the bottom of the form. even after I hard code and set the focus to the first text box of the form.

any ideas?

thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i have tried to sue focus while index change, however, at least, it doesn't work for me.
here is my final solution which is turn off the animation in accordion UI:

```
$("#accordion").accordion(
                     {
                         autoHeight: false,
                         animated: false,
                         active: parseInt(index),
                         event: ""
                     }
);
```

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The page scrolling effect is an artifact of activating (either automatically or manually) an accordion option.

The following code in the `_toggle` function of the `ui.accordion` widget (ui version `1.8.24`) makes an explicit call to the `focus` method:

```
toShow.prev()
    .attr({
        "aria-expanded": "true",
        "aria-selected": "true",
        tabIndex: 0
    })
    .focus();
```

This feature was removed in jQuery UI version `1.9.0` circa October 2012.

To eliminate the page scrolling down effect, either remove the `.focus()` method call or upgrade to a newer version of jQuery UI (recommended).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure without some code if this works, but there is a [change event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#event-change) which according to the doco:

> This event is triggered every time the accordion changes. If the accordion is animated, the event will be triggered upon completion of the animation; otherwise, it is triggered immediately.

So is it possible to use this event and set focus to a valid target once the expand has happened.

I have tested this with the according demo /demos/according/default.html and it is called after the expand:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        change: function(event, ui) {
            alert('blah');
            // Add your focus code in here
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I'd also like to mention in all cases I have used the accordian the page doesn't jump down after expanding.