# jquery accordion scrolls to the active panel on page load

Tags: jquery, accordion, scrolltop

How do I stop scrolling to the panel when the page loads? I've already tried

```
$(window).load(function()
{
     $("html,body").scrollTop(0);
}
```

Comment: Please give us more context.

Comment: something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262924/how-to-stop-page-scrolling-down-while-using-jquery-accordion)? Please be specific